# How to configure custom aspects and retrieve its property using CMIS 1.1 atom binding alfresco 5.0.c?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

Using Alfresco, I have created an aspect and added custom properties to it.

Need help in accessing the custom properties using CMIS 1.1 Atom Binding and Alfresco 5.0.c.

Kindly help me to display the document with its custom properties.

```
    public void uploadDocument(Folder newFolder) {
File file = new File("file.txt");
properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");

properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, file.getName());

properties.put(PropertyIds.CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME,file.getCustomField());


path    = Paths.get(DOC_NAME_WITH_PATH);

content= Files.readAllBytes(path);

contentStream   = new ContentStreamImpl(file.getName(), 
BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), new 
MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file), new 
FileInputStream(file));     

newDoc = (Document)newFolder.createDocument(properties, contentStream, 
VersioningState.MAJOR);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to do the fetch and display?

Comment: We defined aspects in configuration files (extension/mc-model.xml, extension/mc-model-context.xml, messages/customType.property, web-extension/share-config-custom.xml,web-extension/custom-slingshot-application-context.xml ) and we are able to view it alfresco share, but we need help in accessing those aspect properties in a Java code using CMIS 1.1

Comment: And where is the Java code you're using to access via CMIS?

Comment: The code you have given is doing an upload. Where is the fetch code that is / isn't showing the custom aspects?